# More pythonic way to test for is none

Tags: python

Which way to test for a `variable == None` is the more pythonic?

`if var:`

or

`if var is not None`

?

I personally would favor the primer. But the latter is more explicit. 
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

But for what benefit? Beginner programmers - should this be assumed in production grade software?

Comment: Those aren't equivalent statements at all.  `if var:` will skip execution for many values other than `None` - zeros of any numeric type, and empty strings or sequences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You check explicitly with `if var is not None:`

Reason

```
does_not_work = 0

if does_not_work:
    print("Works - is not none")
else:
    print("Is None ... or not?")
```

See  [What is Truthy and Falsy? How is it different from True and False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)

The simple test checks for truthyness - not `None`.

Comment: Python's philosophy is *"Explicit is better than implicit"*, so this is pretty much as pythonic as it gets.

Comment: Ah hell, yes. This is the issue if you do not type the variables. In my case I'm looking at a `datetime` that can be None if some `try except` fails. Note to self - do not mix working on static typed languages and python.

Comment: @r.ook `if some_variable:` is fine if it's what you mean.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski It is absolutely fine - provided the `bool` value is what you're testing for.  There are definitely use cases for the short form `if some_var:`, but in OP's case, explicit test of `is not None` will probably be more beneficial.

Comment: @El  there is no "Falsy" DateTime object, so you would be fine using either. but for integers, strings, lists etc. there are falsy evaluated ones, so don`t use it there if you need to distinguish them  as None from them as Falsy.

Comment: Exactly that was the reason why I asked bc either works in my case.

Answer (score 3):

If `None`-ness is important, and it's possible you'd receive a falsy value that should not be treated equivalently, you have to use `is not None`. But if you're just testing `None` vs. "some other value guaranteed to be truthy", then it's really personal preference.

For example, when testing the result of a regex `.match` call, `if matchobj:` and `if matchobj is not None:` are both fine; `match` returns either `None` for a failed match or a guaranteed truthy match object, so it's mostly a matter of personal style. `if matchobj:` is *microscopically* faster, but not enough to weight the decision meaningfully.

Comment: My above question arose out of the first situation you mention, it's error handling for a datetime var that has to be set or if something fails is None.